# Is the Firebase 'Integrate with Google Cloud' Documentation Outdated?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

## Issue

The ['Integrate with Google Cloud' documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration) instructs to use the generic **google-cloud** library.

`var gcloud = require('google-cloud');`

However, when installing `npm install --save google-cloud` the following message shows using the generic library is deprecated.

> The google-cloud package has been deprecated. We stronglyrecommend installing individual API packages, such as @google-cloud/storage. For a list of Google Cloud Platform API specific packages please visit https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: Your question answers itself, which isn't really the way Stack Overflow works.  Please edit the question to be simply a question alone, then you can answer it using your answer, and mark it as correct.  Otherwise, there is no way this question can be properly closed.

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Following the [**npmjs** documentation for @google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage).

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// The name for the new bucket
const bucketName = 'my-new-bucket';

// Creates the new bucket
storage
  .createBucket(bucketName)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Bucket ${bucketName} created.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
```

I've submitted the following feedback via the *Send Feedback* button on Firebase's documentation page.